# Logstash Filter Grok for custom log

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm using `Logstash` for the first time and I'm trying to map my logs with a grok filter, putting them on an `ElasticSearch` and visualizing with `Kibana`.

This is my current situation:

**Filter**

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP:timestamp} | %{WORD:trackingId} | %{WORD:request} | %{WORD:session} | %{IP:client} | 
      %{WORD:userId} | %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
  }
}
```

**Log**

```
2017-03-21 11:11:54.731 | myApp_35 | myApp_35 | 69E59F4DACC314C0B11B1A8CEA87F9BB | 127.0.0.1 |  | GET on URL [/api/customer] executed with success in [18555 us].
```

Apparently this is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{WORD:trackingId}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{WORD:request}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{WORD:session}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{IP:client}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{DATA:userId}%{SPACE}\|%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

Based on OPs comment here is another regex with SPACE replaced by \s*

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s*\|\s*%{WORD:trackingId}\s*\|\s*%{WORD:request}\s*\|\s*%{WORD:session}\s*\|\s*%{IP:client}\s*\|\s*%{DATA:userId}\s*\|\s*%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

I would recommend this site to test your grok regex: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Apparently %{SPACE} was not working. I replaced it with a simple space char and everything worked fine! Can you modify the answer? Then I'll accept it :)

Comment: Actually SPACE is defined in the grok patterns. see here: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns#L13

Comment: @Nano Please check if the update is ok .I replaced %{SPACE} with \s* which will look for space (0 or more times). Please accept the answer if this helps you.